# package for graph creation and processing in python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to create and process graphs, for example, checking if a graph contains a cycle and I'm doing this in python.

Is there an API or Library that has implemented these basic capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I know about `NetworkX` library.

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_edges_from([(0, 1),(0, 2),(0, 3),(8, 9)])
l = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(G1))
# Gives a list of all strong connected components
# You can also try 
# l = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G1))
# To check if the we can reach from one node to other in undirected graph
for graph in l:
    nx.draw_networkx(graph)
```

It is has been quite easy to use with `pandas` and `numpy` in various projects.